# Code coverage report without running test

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, code-coverage, emma

I would like to create report from my unit tests without running them. I would like only analyze test source code and check which methods have been called. In my tests I use JUnit, Arquillian. I run them on external server and I had problems with using arquillian-jacoco extension. After instrumentation application could not start properly. Is there any tool which provide such functionality?

Comment: There is no tool available to get the code coverage without running the test cases. That is for a logical reason, as coverage means how much code is covered by your test cases. Without running the test cases, any claim will be flawed.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no tools that can give you code coverage without running through it.

Comment: It sounds like your real problem is why your code coverage isn't working. Perhaps you should re-write your question so that *this* is the focus - after all, proper code coverage is what you want!

Comment: This is an old question. You can of course instrument your code and then check the coverage. For example with jacoco just run mvn jacoco:prepare-agent and than start your jvm with the given parameter. After your tests(or whatever you wanna do), you can run mvn jacoco:report and get a nice coverage report.

Answer (score 2):

*Code Coverage* is not just about which methods are called. It goes one more level deep and checks which lines within a method were covered (actually executed) during your test cases.

So, it's less about simply having a call to a method as part of your code and more about whether any of the execution flows actually invoke that method or not. And, the execution flows would mostly depend on the test case inputs. So, unless you run them a code coverage tool is pretty much clueless here.

Assuming, you have some code like

```
if (size > 0) {
    this.array = new Integer[size];
} else {
    String msg = "Input size must be > 0";
    logAndThrow(msg, new IllegalArgumentException(msg));
}
```

Now, what you're effectively saying is to treat `logAndThrow()` as covered which certainly is not the case unless you have some test case that tests this class with `size <= 0`.

Answer (score 1):

While there are already great answers, I would like to add that a lot of things cannot be simply determined at compile time, and consequently can only be identified at run time. Polymorphism is a great example for this.

Answer (score 0):

One *can* get code coverage without executing code, via static analysis, essentially by [slicing your code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_slicing) from each unit test.  See the technical paper [Static Estimation of Test Coverage](http://www.computer.org/csdl/proceedings/scam/2009/3793/00/3793a055-abs.html).

Having said that, I don't think there are presently any production tools that implement this idea.